# Apache blocking all request

Tags: apache2

My apache configuration seems a bit weird. I have three applications running on 3 domains with the same IP. Now I have 3 conf files like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName app.domain.com:80

  # Redirect any non HTTPS requests to the HTTPS server
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://app.domain.com$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName app.domain.com:443

  SSLCertificateFile [...]/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile [...]/privkey.pem
  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

  # ... application
</VirtualHost>
```

This works (kinda, there are problems when running collabora for nextcloud, might be an issue outside apache though).
Except now when I access the IP address directly, I get one of the applications, which I don't want. So I tried to apply the solution mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/583884/apache-listen-only-on-specific-domain-not-ip), but then all access to any domain gets blocked.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have DNS Name set correctly set for all 3 sites pointing to your host.

It will not work until you have correct DNS set correctly.

Comment: I think I do, but how do I check?

Comment: check via nslookup and see if its pointing to correct server.

Comment: It does, but it says `canonical name`?

Comment: thats fine as far as it is pointing to correct host.

Comment: Try adding virtualhost parameters as below for port 80 and similar for port 443.

<VirtualHost \*:80>

      ServerName  app.domain.com

      ServerAlias app.domain.com

    </VirtualHost>

Comment: No change. I also tried setting server as `app1...` and alias as `app{2,3}...`, then domain results in app1.